# Relationship of 'C3' to Delta-V for interplanetary missions

Tags: interplanetary, trajectory

In what way does the concept of '[C3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4056/12978)' relate to 'Delta-V' in interplanetary missions?

Answer (score 4):

That depends on how and where the $\Delta V$ is applied. It is usually applied as an impulsive burn in low-Earth orbit. In that case (assuming a circular LEO, $\mu$ is GM, $r$ is distance from Earth center):

$$\Delta V=\sqrt{C_3+{2\mu_{Earth}\over r_{LEO}}} - \sqrt{\mu_{Earth}\over r_{LEO}}$$

Ah, looks like I've [answered this one before](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/4057/265).

Comment: I've just asked [How to interpret and use characteristic energy C3?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26090/12102) in reference to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26074/12102).